# C#։ Голосовой ассистент работает неправильно

Tags: c#

У меня голосовой ассистент который должен отвечать на команды, но он выполняет 1-2 команд потом зависает. Что с кодом не так?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{ 
    static SpeechSynthesizer _SS = new SpeechSynthesizer(); 
    static void sayq(String words) 
    { 
        _SS.SpeakAsync(words); 
    } 
    public Form1() 
    { 
        InitializeComponent(); 
    } 
    static Label l; 

    static void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e) 
    {
        if (e.Result.Confidence > 0.52) 
        { 
            if (e.Result.Text == "один") 
            {
                l.Text = "Один"; sayq("цифра один!"); 
            }
            else if (e.Result.Text == "два") 
            { 
                sayq("цифра Два!"); 
                l.Text = "Два"; 
            } 
            else if (e.Result.Text == "привет") { 
                sayq("Здравствуйте!!! Я голосовой помощник от pafimov! Спросите у меня что-либо или скажите комманды для списка команд!"); 
                l.Text = "Здравствуйте!!!"; 
            } 
            else if (e.Result.Text == "пока") 
            { 
                sayq("До свидания!!!"); 
                l.Text = "Пока!"; 
                Thread.Sleep(1500); 
                Application.Exit(); 
            } 
            else if (e.Result.Text == "команды") 
            { 
                sayq("открыть поиск, открыть профиль создателя, открыть соц сеть, пока, и так далее"); 
                l.Text = "Список команд"; 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        l = label2_result; 


        System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-ru"); 
        SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ci); 
        sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice(); 

        sre.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRecognized); 

        Choices numbers = new Choices(); 
        numbers.Add(new String[] { "один", "два", "три", "четыре", "пять","привет","пока","мяу","гав", "команды" }); 


        GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder(); 
        gb.Append(numbers); 

        Grammar g = new Grammar(gb); 
        if (Convert.ToString(g) == "один") { l.Text = "qqq"; } 
        sre.LoadGrammar(g); 

        sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Вопрос составил неправильно, теперь исправил.